# Automate backup of Enterprise Architect data

Tags: database, enterprise-architect

We are using Enterprise Architect for our models and it uses a database to save all of its data. We now need to have a daily "dump" of the data so that we can store it in our configuration management system. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific built-in function for this. EA has a couple of options for version control, but they are based on packages, not the entire project.

(Btw, using an external version control system in conjunction with a database-stored EA project is not recommended, so don't start down that path unless you are absolutely certain of what you're doing; use EA's baselines instead.)

Dumping a project is easy to do manually using the "Project Transfer" function (under Tools - Data Management). This allows you to transfer an entire project from a database to an .EAP file (and the three other combos as well). The process typically takes less than a minute.

This function is also available in the EA API (Project::ProjectTransfer), so if you want to automate it you can do so. In a previous job I designed and implemented a version control solution where this was one component, so it can be done and it isn't even all that hard.

Comment: Example code seems a little lacking for this. Do you have any example code or can point to any documentation on how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be old, but to document some example code of a VBScript from Geert Bellekens

```
sub main

Dim CurrentDate
Currentdate = Replace(Date, "/", "-") 

dim repository
dim projectInterface
set repository = CreateObject("EA.Repository")

Dim FileName
Filename = "EA_Export.eap"

dim LogFilePath
LogFilePath = "C:\EA\EA_to_EAP.log"

dim TargetFilePath
TargetFilePath = "C:\EA\EA_Export.eap"

dim eapString
eapString = "EAConnectString:DB_EA_PROD --- DBType=1;Connect=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DB_EA_PROD;Data Source=BESQLCP;LazyLoad=1;"

'get project interface
set projectInterface = repository.GetProjectInterface()

projectInterface.ProjectTransfer eapString, TargetFilePath, LogFilePath

'repository.CloseFile
repository.Exit 

Dim newFilename 
newFilename = "C:\EA\EAP_Files\EA_Export_" & CurrentDate & ".eap"

Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Fso.MoveFile "C:\EA\EA_Export.eap", newFileName

end sub

main
```

Referenced from: http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,37635.msg235329.html#msg235329